# Entire Function such that $n^{-n/2}f^{(n)}(0)\in \mathbb{Z},n\geq 1$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be an entire function such that $n^{-n/2}f^{(n)}(0)\in \mathbb{Z},n\geq 1$ and $f$ is not a polynomial. Show that $\limsup_{\lvert z\rvert\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\log\lvert f(z)\rvert}{\lvert z\rvert}\geq 2$. Can anyone give me a clue or an idea or a precise answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $f(z)=\sum_na_nn^{n/2}z^n/n!$, where infinitely many $a_n$ are non-zero integers, so $|a_n|\geq 1$ for those $n$. By Cauchy inequality, for every $n$
and for every $r$, we have
$$\max_{|z|=r}|f(z)|\geq n^{n/2}r^n/n!,$$
so, using Stirling formula,
$$\log\max_{|z|=r}|f(z)|\geq n-(n/2)\log n+n\log r+O(\log n).$$
Now maximize the RHS with respect to $n$. To do this, treat $n$ as a continuous variable, so that you can use Calculus. You obtain that the maximum is attained
aproximately at $n=r^2$. Now forget this non-rigorous argument and just plug
$n=r^2$, or more precisely, take $n$ for which $a_n\neq 0$, and choose $r=\sqrt{n}$. You obtain
$$\limsup_{r\to\infty}\frac{\log|f(z)|}{|z|^2}\geq 1,$$
which is much stronger than what you wanted.

Comment: I am a little bit tired! I  do not understand why you put $logmax$ at $|z|=1$? How can i get my inequality by your last statement ?

Comment: This was a misprint. I corrected. How do you get your inequality? Using that $|z|^2>2|z|$ when $|z|$ is large.

Comment: Very nice ! Did you use the formula $\log n! = n\log n + n - 1/2\log n - \log(\sqrt(2\pi))- 1/12n + o(1/n)$ ?

Comment: Yes, but only the first 2 terms of this asymptotics are relevant.